# Override constraints error message not working in Grails

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-2.0

I'm trying to override grails default error message for minSize constraint but I always get the default message. I wrote the following code in my message.properties file

```
Student.firstName.invalid.min.size.message
```

I also tried to use the full package name but still with no luck. Is there anybody can help me with that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct message code to use is specified at the bottom of the reference page for each constraint in the grails user guide. In the case of [minSize](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/minSize.html) you need

```
className.propertyName.minSize.notmet
```